# Interface builder Designables started failing

Tags: xcode, xcode6, storyboard, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I have some IBDesignables in my storyboard. These Designables worked perfectly yesterday... but now when I open the storyboard all Designables fails to build >:(

Ive tried:

- refreshing all views: Editor->Refresh All Views
- restarting Xcode
- restarting my computer
- terminating the Interface builder related processes in Activity Monitor.

Im using Xcode 6.3.2